# What would be the behavior of the electric field in extremely long superconductor wires?

Tags: electricity, superconductivity

I have that very simple physics question. Imagine a simple Battery-resistor circuit (basic Ohm's law), but with two extremely long superconductor wires (1 light-year long, this is, 9 460 730 472 580,8 km). **Initially, there is no contact between the battery and the very long wires. This simple problem begins when you connect the battery and the wires** (the resistor is located far, far away).

[image: Circuit explained below]

How would the electric field (and maybe the current, too) behave in such situation. Should I take into account the Einstein's relativity theory?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming it is steady state then there's nothing special to be done.  (What's with all of these pseudo-transmission line problems showing up lately anyway?)

Comment: Uhmmm. No steady-state. What  would be the behavior of the electric field when you start connecting the battery to that hypothetical circuit? I must be editing my text. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please add those details to the question, they are very relevant.  For these problems the initial conditions are critical.

Comment: Hint: The electric field outside the wires (typically pointing from one wire to the other) is more important than the electric field inside the wires. And the material outside the wires is not a superconductor. Often in circuits and electromagnetics we assume (as a reasonable approximation) that all metal objects have 0 resistivity. Building a structure out of actual superconductor would just make the behavior closer to our ideal model, not cause any new or unexpected behavior.